# Cannot undelete my answers when I am out of undelete votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, undelete

Trying to be helpful I have voted to reopen several questions today and so I have no more undelete votes.

The side effect of this is that I cannot undelete my answers, which is a pain when I delete them to fix and error and then want to undelete them again. I just get the message "You've reached the maximum number of 3 Undeletion votes today; come back in 6 hours"

Although I haven't checked, I would assume that as delete votes are also rate limited, the reverse is also true and you are not able to delete your answer if you have voted to delete x questions.

Given that deleting/undeleting your own questions doesn't (as far as I know) add to the limit, why is it affected by it.

Comment: Why are you deleting answers to fix them?

Comment: @Robert A tactic used by some people is to delete a question when significant edits are necessary that occupy an extended period of time. This prevents the post from being voted or commented on while it is in an incomplete or incorrect state.

Comment: @Robert I occasionally post answers that deserve downvotes (i.e. they are wrong) but are fixable.

Comment: ...that comment of mine should read "delete an answer", not question. Not many people delete questions considering most people can't see the question after doing so...